# Geometric meaning of the extrinsic curvature neck

Tags: riemannian-geometry, flows

I'm reading by myself "[Mean curvature flow with surgeries of two–convex hypersurfaces](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00222-008-0148-4)" (it's free available, it's just click on "Download PDF" on the upper right corner side) by Gerhard Huisken and Carlo Sinestrari and I'm stuck in understand the definition of extrinsic curvature neck on pages $147$ and $148$. I would like to understand what this means geometrically, I know that this definition seems intuitive, but I will try explain below why I understood and why I think I didn't understand well.

$\textbf{My thoughts:}$

Firstly, I watched [this seminar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xI7AJPZ1SC4) on Youtube given by Huisken about this article. Huisken explains that in the mean curvature flow for higher dimensions there are three possibilities of singularities during the evolution by the mean curvature flow (it's the explanation given in 17:42 to 20:48 on the video), so the geometric idea that I have in mind concerning to extrinsic curvature necks is that the necks can be seen as cylinders or round spheres, in particular, I think that the extrinsic curvature $(\varepsilon,k)$-spherical on $M^n$ means that you are approximating the extrinsic curvature of cross sections of Neckpinch and Degenerate Neckpinch (see 17:42 on the video for a picture of these Neckpinchs), while the extrinsic curvature $(\varepsilon,k,L)$-cylindrical around $p$ would be a way to approximate the extrinsic curvature of those Neckpinchs in the neck by the extrinsic curvature of the cylinder, but there are some points unclear according my interpretation, which I list below:

1. My interpretation doesn't justify the necessity to define $(\varepsilon,k)$-parallel extrinsic curvature and I can't see what this definition means geometrically;
2. I don't be sure if this definition is a notion of convergence or not as I thinking because they didn't say if $\varepsilon > 0$ is arbitrarly or not (I believe that, in fact, we can suppose without loss of generality that $\varepsilon > 0$ because the proposition $3.2$ and $3.3$ on article basically say this);
3. Supposing that I understood correctly the definition, I don't know if my interpretation is concerning to the neckpinchs or if it is concerned to a hypersurface which enclose the neckpinch or the degenerate neckpinch (see on pages $71$ and $91$ of [this beamer presentation](http://www.math-berlin.de/images/stories/head-bmsdays.pdf), which was done by a former student of Huisken, pictures of the what is I'm talking about).

Anyway, I don't understand exactly the geometric meaning of the extrinsic curvature necks, principally, the condition of parallelism.

I will be grateful if someone can help me.